# Prime Number Theory Proof

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, prime-numbers

Suppose $p$ is a prime ordinary integer and $w$ is a prime extended integer, where $w = a+b\cdot\sqrt{3}$, and that $p | N(w)$ (as ordinary integers). Prove that $w | p$. 
[Hint: Since w is prime, we know that either $w | p$ or $(w, p) = 1$.]

So within the hint, I figured we can use these as cases and then show that $(w, p) = 1$ isn't true but I'm not quite sure how to do that since we only know $w$ is prime? Also, I'm not quite sure how the $N(w)$ helps within the problem? We know that $N(w) = (a+b\cdot\sqrt{3})\cdot(a-b\cdot\sqrt{3})$ and that since $p | N(w)$, then $N(w) = p\cdot k$, but I don't see how this helps with the proof? Any help or just nudge in the right direction would be GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: What is meant by $(w,p)$?

Comment: Why is it the case that if $w \nmid p$, then $(w,p) = 1$? Can't the gcd be any unit in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{3}]$

Comment: @skyking, it means the greatest common divisor of the two is 1 and therefore $w$ and $p$ can be written as a linear combination of 1.

Comment: @mathworker21 when we say 1 I think it means just the ordinary integer (which can also be written as an extended integer). We proved earlier that these were situationals when dealing with primes. [not sure if that actually answers your question, but this is what I know we've done]